# Why isn't my time series plotting correctly?

Tags: r, plot, time-series

I am trying to plot a time series of daily discharge from 2010 to 2022, however, the plot does not look correct.

I first created a variable for discharge using the code:
`Discharge <- PrecipDischarge.dat$Discharge`

I then created a time series using the code:

`discharge.ts <- ts(Discharge, start = c(2010,5), end = c(2022,10), frequency = 184)`

I then plotted the discharge time series using the code:

`plot.ts(discharge.ts, xlab = "Date", ylab = "Daily Discharge (m3/s)"`

When I plot each of these time series, the time series does not appear to reflect my data, and is following a cyclic pattern (i.e., the section of the time plot from 2012 to 2013 is identical to the section of the time plot from 2018 to 2019, the section of the time plot from 2013 to 2014 is identical to the section of the time plot from 2019 to 2020).

I have plotted the same data is excel using a line graph, and the data and the plot looks like it is correct. Why am I unable to produce these plots in R?

I tried looking at the raw data to ensure that this cyclic pattern isn't actually present in the time series, and plotted the data in Excel to see if I got a similar plot. The excel plot appears correct, and very different from my results in R.

[Incorrect Time Series Plot From R](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HgJrL.jpg)

Does anyone know why the R plot is not representing the true data?

TIA

Comment: You are probably using a wrong frequency when creating the `"ts"` object. If your original data has a date column try package `zoo`.